# How to fetch an object from collection?

Tags: nhibernate

I have 3 classes, Addin, Application and Database. Each addin can have many applications and each application has only 1 database. I want to get 1 addin and fetch all applications with their databases.

Addin<-> Application= 1:m
Application <-> Database= 1:1

This query only fetches the applications. How to fetch the database:

```
    var result session.CreateCriteria<Addin>()
           .SetFetchMode("applications", FetchMode.Eager)
           .Future<Addin>();

    result.ToList();
```

Comment: Unless Criteria work differently in Hibernate and NHibernate, you should be able to SetFetchMode("Database", FetchMode.Eager) on a property too.

Comment: It is not working in NHibernate.

Comment: Ah, I misread your associations, thought Database was a property on Addin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use joins or you can change the mapping options to load the Database together with the Application (I suppose that in the model you have Database as property of Application)

It will look smth. like

```
session.QueryOver<Addin>()
              .JoinAlias(x => x.Database, () => database)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: I have no properties but fields. Addin do not know about Database.

Comment: Try this: I'm not sure about the syntax (no editor opened)



`session
                .CreateCriteria<Addin>() 
                .CreateAlias("Applications", "apps") 
                .CreateAlias("apps.Database", "db") 
                .SetFetchMode("applications", FetchMode.Join)  
                .SetFetchMode("apps.Database", FetchMode.Join) `

Comment: I tried this earlier today and it says that app prop does not exist :(